# jQuery UI Autocomplete - style like a standard <SELECT>

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm on the verge of starting a new web application that is likely to have need for both standard, simple  dropdowns as well as more feature-rich autocomplete controls for longer lists of values, better type ahead behavior, etc.  I'm planning on using the jQuery UI Autocomplete widget along with some combobox behavior as detailed here:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox

My concern is that "out of the box" the Autocomplete widget looks very different than a standard  control.  Since  is not easy to skin/style, I'm hoping to adjust the Autocomplete to look & feel as close to the  as possible, except in the cases where the increased functionality justifies a different L&F.

What is the best way to go about reskinning the Autocomplete to look more like a ?  Has this already been done somewhere?  Should I use jQuery UI theming?  Other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The autocomplete control already uses the jQuery UI theming :)

Change the style with the dropdown in the upper right of that [page you linked here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox) to see.

Those are the default themes available. but you can of course tweak the theme yourself.  All jQuery UI widgets conform to this theming scheme. [They provide a tool you can customize the theme with as well, called ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/).  You'll see autocomplete on the right in ThemeRoller, it will be styled live as you make changes to the theme.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I am aware that the widget supports theming but I guess what I'm getting at is whether it is appropriate to use theming for this purpose?  Is there a theme that will make it look more like the <SELECT> out of the box?  Will ThemeRoller let me get there easily enough?

Comment: @jkohlhepp - Yes, you can theme however you like, just visit ThemeRoller and start playing, you can setup your theme then when ready it's setup for you to download 1 zip file containing all the javascript, css, and images you need for all your jQuery UI stuff.  Just use the "download theme" button on the left when you're happy with the styling.